# OSM table(Matrix) Api returning distance 0 for small routes

Tags: openstreetmap, routing, api, distance-matrix

I am building a webservice which returns distance of various shops, from lat,long received from mobile.

For that I want to use osm table api, but it return zero for search on lat,long:

Click on link:
http://router.project-osrm.org/table/v1/drive/22.9755,72.5024;23.0143,72.5647;23.0483,72.4796?sources=0

Here I'm search for below matrix:

```
     From       |       To
22.9755,72.5024 |  23.0143,72.5647
22.9755,72.5024 |  23.0483,72.4796
```

If I search manually in there website (http://www.openstreetmap.org/search) and it return correct distance.

Comment: Those coordinates in Ahmedabad, right ?

Comment: Hi Shady, correct It is in Ahmedabad

Comment: Well, now your URL works well as per below answer

Comment: @Shaddy, Thanks, link is working fine now, but it is returning `durations` and not distance, do you have link for me about documentations

Comment: https://github.com/Project-OSRM/osrm-backend/blob/master/docs/http.md#service-table

Comment: Thanks, it is saying it returns `table |  computes distance tables for given coordinates` but seems not returning

Comment: You may try tracing the service used on main website, as below but after summarizing :https://router.project-osrm.org/route/v1/driving/72.497597,22.97139;72.564588,23.014073?overview=false&alternatives=false&steps=false  this is the main:  https://router.project-osrm.org/route/v1/driving/72.497597,22.97139;72.564588,23.014073?overview=false&alternatives=true&steps=true&hints=Vrv8iESAQ4lg14wAAAAAAPMAAAA0CQAA3AEAAOE3nwQ6N58Em7QAAL05UgT9g14BvTlSBP6DXgEaAAEBbg_PNg==;n1XJiBrvVo0AAAAAAQAAAAYAAAAzAAAAMgAAALYZtwayGbcGm7QAADE_UwS2Kl8BbD9TBLkqXwEEAAEBbg_PNg==

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to swap the coordinates, Lat in place of long and long in place of lat as below:

http://router.project-osrm.org/table/v1/drive/72.5024,22.9755;72.5647,23.0143;72.4796,23.0483?sources=0